# Any shorter solution for select - from - where LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I have the search function. and I want to select all value in my Book table which contain `_searchdata` but I dont know how to express at "where" with the short code instead of listing all items of Table like this:
(I just get some items for example, it contains about 100 items like `Booktitle`, `Author`, `Genre`... i dont want to specify it because it's so long)

```
public void SearchAny(string _searchdata)
{
    var searchAnyInDB = from Book x in BookDB.Books
                        where (x.BookTitle.Contains(_searchdata)
                               || x.Author.Contains(_searchdata)
                               || x.Genre.Contains(_searchdata))
                        select x;
    DataSearch.Clear();
    DataSearch = new ObservableCollection<Book>(searchAnyInDB);
}
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to specify `BookTitle` `Author` and so forth?

Comment: @I3arnon yes. that what i mean

Comment: @AntP - It's not about code-review (the OP wants to improve this code).

Comment: I've retracted my closevote. At first sight it might seem as codereview, but I believe it isn't in its essence. He wants to know a way to query every property, this is just a sample.

Comment: Isn't that a try of implementing full text search using LINQ?

Comment: refactor the where part with a method call. The method will do what you've written in the where clause and return a boolean as per your logic.

Comment: @AntP because my Book table contains many properties. so if i list all them...it is so long

Comment: @deostroll: self defined methods aren't likely to work in LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel just u understand clearly what I mean

Comment: Well from the looks of it, this should be a pure db operation where you'd need a stored proc to do this job.

Answer (score 4):

Because LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL both use `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` as `IQueryable.Where` extension method parameter, you can use reflection to create that `Expression` during compile type and generate all there `||` instead of typing them into your source code.

Would be something like:

```
    var searchAnyInDB = from Book x in BookDB.Books
                        where (GetWhereExpression<Book>(_searchdata))
                        select x;
```

And `GetWhereExpression<TSource>` method:

```
static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> GetWhereExpression<TSource>(string value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var val = Expression.Constant(value);
    var expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(1));

    foreach(var prop in typeof(TSource).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            expression = Expression.OrElse(expression,
                            Expression.Call(
                                Expression.Property(param, prop),
                                "Contains",
                                null,
                                val
                            )
                        );
        }
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(expression, param);
}
```

You still can do better then that, ex. remembering the expression for type to prevent using reflection every time you need to execute the query with different search texts, etc. But it should give you an idea where to go.

Comment: could u show the code exactly? I still dont understand what u mean. thanks